# How to Leverage browser caching URLs?

Tags: caching

I'm optimising website and through the checkup it was suggested to leverage browser caching for following links.

> https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-40514212-1 (15 minutes)
>   https://connect.facebook.net/sk_SK/sdk.js (20 minutes)
>   https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js (60
>   minutes) https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)

How do I do that and where?

Comment: I see some kind of assignment needs answer on SO!

Comment: what does SO stand for please?

Comment: Stack Overflow!

Comment: you find any solution?